# retrieve a single query from a data base in android by sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve a single row from my database using `SQLite` but for some reason my program crashes. When I search the log I get the next error:

> Index -1 is requested with size of 1

I searched the web for solutions but it looks like my code is correct. I can delete a row with that parameter so I know that the position is right. It's probably how I write the query but I just don't know what's wrong with it. Can someone see why I'm doing wrong?
This is the code for the query:

```
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY +   /jokes_table");

    final Uri _URI = Uri.parse(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/2");
        String positions = intent.getStringExtra("position_in_db");
        Cursor cur = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(_URI, new String[] {"Joke","Author","Date","Status"} , MyContentProvider.ID + " = " + intent.getStringExtra("position_in_db") , null , null );
```

my query method :

```
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    String a;
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) 
    { 
    case COLLECTION_URI_INDICATOR: 
        qb.setTables(TABLE_NAME); 
        qb.setProjectionMap(projectionMap); 
        break; 
    case SINGLE_ITEM_URI_INDICATOR: 
        qb.setTables(TABLE_NAME); 
        qb.setProjectionMap(projectionMap); 
        qb.appendWhere(ID);
        break; 
    default: 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri); 
    } 
    SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null); 

    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri); 
    return c; 

}
```

When I try to get all the rows by that query it works fine. The only problem is that I can't retrieve specific row. I try to change the selection with `?` and try to see the string before I call the query but it won't work. Trying to reach data from the cursor by

```
    cur.getString(getColumnIndex("Joke"));
```

ends the program. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

What is your `selection` and `selectionArgs`??

you can try this

```
selection = ROW_ID_COLUMN_NAME + " =? "; // take a note on the "Space" between this statement
selectionArgs = { ROW_ID };

c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

// moveToFirst() method may prevent error when accessing 0 row cursor.
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    c.getString(getColumnIndex("Joke"));
}
```

Comment: the program still crash.
if I add the if (c.moveToFirst()) it will point the first row and i want it to point to a specific row.

Comment: post your logcat, and will see what cause the crash

Comment: yeah, but if your selection is `rowID` which should be unique, then you will only get 1 row from your cursor, moveToFirst() won't be a problem.